# For mysql statement, theifnull function is not working as intended. Why?

Tags: mysql, ifnull

Table inputs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNM6Z.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8roLD.png)

Help me figure out what's wrong.

Tried this

```
Select ifnull(count(distinct t.client_id), 0) as Cancelled, t.request_at as Day
from Trips t
left join Users u on t.client_id = u.users_id or t.driver_id = u.users_id
where t.status != "completed" and u.banned = "No"
group by Day
```

and expected output is:

| Cancelled | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2013-10-01 |
| 1 | 2013-10-03 |
| 0 | 2013-10-02 |

and my output is:

| Cancelled | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2013-10-01 |
| 1 | 2013-10-03 |

Comment: `count` will always return a row, it is **counting** whatever you added added as a filter on your query so it will be either 0 or the number of rows that matches you filter. Never null.

Comment: I've edited and formated your question and you replaced it by Images. Please don't do that. Images are the worst for this kind of post. You can look at the edit history and bring it back.

Comment: Logically, how would you include a row from the `Trips` table and so have a value for `Day` but have no value for `client_id`?

Comment: this is a leetcode problem, right?

Comment: `... left join Users u ... where ... and u.banned = "No" ...` converts your LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN. Move this condition to ON clause.